# Getting error - py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o115.save

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Have a pyspark code which is running succesfully as per scehdule every month. It failed this month; we have not made any changes to the code or the configuration. Have looked at all the similar threads but one seems to help.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

The complete traceback is as -
'''
Significant Credit Monthly starts at 2020-12-04 17:55:04.761266

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/code/sig_cr_dc/Sig_CD_Monthly1.py", line 105, in <module>
    Sig_Cdt_Stats.write.mode("overwrite").save(Sig_Cdt_Path)
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.0-1.cdh5.11.0.p2245.2467/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 397, in save
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.0-1.cdh5.11.0.p2245.2467/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.0-1.cdh5.11.0.p2245.2467/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.0-1.cdh5.11.0.p2245.2467/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o115.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.dataSource$lzycompute$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameWriter$$dataSource$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$save$1.apply$mcV$sp(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.executeAndCallQEListener(DataFrameWriter.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:172)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 164 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 164.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 18018, kmblhdpdata2.kbank.kotakgroup.com, executor 149): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 149 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1421)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1644)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1603)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1592)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1862)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1875)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1952)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
        ... 31 more
'''
```

Comment: See the error log - This complains about huge file size - "Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 164 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 164.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 18018, kmblhdpdata2.kbank.kotakgroup.com, executor 149): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 149 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
Driver stacktrace:" - try to debug if you have a huge chnage in the file size

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the point you are making as have faces similar issue in the past. The code ran successfully without making any changes though. Its the only point I fail to understand about the overhead memory that it works on default values sometimes and fails sometimes